# whenever gem works with puts statement but breaks with more code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, whenever

I have gotten the whenever gem to work with a simple puts statement:

## schedule.rb

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

every 1.minutes do
    rake "test_printing"
end
```

## lib/tasks/scheduler.rb

```
task :test_printing => :environment do
  puts "SOME OUTPUT BEFORE CREATE CALL"
  Team.create name: DateTime.now
  puts "SOME OUTPUT AFTER CREATE CALL"
end
```

For some reason, it does not create a new team.  Here are the logs:

```
SOME OUTPUT BEFORE CREATE CALL
SOME OUTPUT BEFORE CREATE CALL
SOME OUTPUT BEFORE CREATE CALL
SOME OUTPUT BEFORE CREATE CALL
```

I tried running the rake task on its own without whenever and it works perfectly.  How do I fix this?

Comment: `puts` != `PUTS`

Comment: ahh, true but unfortunately that was a stackoverflow error.  It's lowercase and correct in my code.

Comment: It's probably a validation error, you can get an exception with `Team.create!`

Comment: It's not because it works if i just run the rake task without whenever.

Comment: How can you know that if you are just letting it silently fail? Use `.create!` and it will tell why the record is not being created.